# Creating a fixed size grid with a variable amount of cells

Tags: css, grid

I'm trying to create a grid up to 64x64 that is contained in a 960x960 pixel container. Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how to accomplish that. I tried doing it percentage based, but then my cells completely disappeared. Can anyone give me any insight?

```
.square 
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;

    height: 1.67%;  // I have no idea what I'm doing here
    max-height: 6.25%;
    width: 1.67%;
    max-width: 6.25%;

    background-color: white;
}

#container
{
    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;

    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways you could do this depending on exactly what you're looking for, but here is one solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8STb/)

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 480px;
    max-width: 480px;
    background: red;
}

.square {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* or use float: left; */
    background: yellow;
}
```

And here is a completely responsive version: [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/8d9aZ/)

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 480px;
    max-width: 480px;
    background: red;
}

.square {
    padding-bottom: 19%;
    width: 19%;
    display: inline-block;
    /* or use float: left; */
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use 19% in your second example?

Comment: obviously, if you do 20%, you should have 5 blocks across, right? well, inline-block adds spacing between each block therefore, at 20%, you will only have 4 across (20%+6(?)px is greater than 100%). float:left would not do that. either way, it's just an example and you can change the numbers as you please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the original code the size of the `.square` is wrong. If each row or column measures `960px` and you want to have a `64 x 64` grid, each cell should measure `1 / 64` of the total, that is `960px / 64 = 15px`. In `%` it would be `100% / 64 = 1.5625%`.

This way you will have a 64x64 grid whatever the size of the `#container` is, although multiples of 64 will be the best option because all the cells will have the same size.

```js
const cells = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 4096; ++i) {
  cells.push('<div class="square"></div>');
}

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = cells.join('');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}

#container {
  position:relative;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: none;
}
.square {
  position:relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 1.5625%;
  height: 1.5625%;
  float: left;
}

.square:hover {
  background: #F00;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 32px 8px #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Alternatively, you could consider using [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).